# Mystery code: +i+ and +x+

Tags: javascript

In the following code:

```
for (i=0; i<itemsinlist.length; i++) {
        var rating = document.createElement('div');
        itemsinlist[i].appendChild(rating);
        rating.className = "rating";
        rating.id = "thumbnails" +i;

        for (x=0; x<4; x++) {
        star = document.createElement('span');
        star.innerHTML = "&#9733;";
        star.className = "star";
        star.setAttribute("onclick", "ratingsSet("+i+","+x+");");
        rating.appendChild(star);
} //createratingsstars
```

I'm struggling to make sense of the second parameter to `star.setAttribute()`, in the line:

```
star.setAttribute("onclick", "ratingsSet("+i+","+x+");");
```

Specifically, I'm being thrown off by the `+i+` and `+x+`.

At first I thought these were some kind of variation on the increment operator, but later decided it must be concatenating something, but I can't figure out what/how. The HTML that gets generated by the loop is:

```
<span class="star" onclick="ratingsSet(0,0);">*</span>
<span class="star" onclick="ratingsSet(0,1);">*</span>
<span class="star" onclick="ratingsSet(0,2);">*</span>
<span class="star" onclick="ratingsSet(0,3);">*</span>
```

But my reverse-engineering chops are failing me (if I had any to begin with).

Help?

Comment: FYI, adding click event handler using the setAttribute method won't work in some browsers. Use `star.onclick = function() { ... };`.

Comment: It's a pretty nasty way to set a click event is what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's string concatenation. `i` is the outer loop counter, and `x` is the inner loop counter. It appears to be iterating a collection and creating 4 spans per item.

Comment: Ah, I was misreading what the '"' are wrapping. I was interpreting the +i+ and +x+ as being wrapped in quotes, but in fact they're sitting outside the quotes, and thus concatenating. Ugh, so obvious now. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick: Syntax highlightning helps with this kind of problem ;)

Comment: @elusive - Right you are. And the editor I'm using (Espresso) indeed highlights it. I simply wasn't looking at it. Newbie mistake, I realize.

Answer (score 4):

It's putting together this string:

```
"ratingsSet(0,1);"
```

The value `0` is in the variable `i`, and the value `1` is in the variable `x`. If we add some spaces, it might be more clear:

```
 "ratingsSet(" + i + "," + x + ");"
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell it increments `i` and `x` and sets attribute on click for element that is:

```
"ratingsSet("+i+","+x+");"
```

Then after click `ratingsSet("+i+","+x+");` with params is executed.

Weird way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks. What's a "less weird" way to do it?

Comment: The statement `"ratingsSet("+i+","+x+");"` does not increment anything. It concatenates those values. What is weird about that?

Comment: Proper way IMHO would be to attach event handler to element instead adding an attribute.

Comment: @elusive statement does not, script does. Look above, there is for that iterates over item length, then for each iteration it sets attribute to element as onclick.

Comment: You'd have to deal with changing value `i`, probably by creating a closure on each iteration. It might be more proper, but certainly less readable and slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can have more readable code:

```
star.onclick = function() {
   ratingsSet(i, x);
};
```

Setting event handler as attribute breaks in older browsers plus not very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript allows you to concatenate strings and integers (and, AFAIK, the string representation of any object) with the plus operator. The resulting HTML (with its embedded JavaScript!) is just that: instantiations of calls to `ratingsSet()`.

Answer (score 0):

"+" is a infix operator that concatenate two strings.

Example : "mor"+"ning" will give the string "morning".

So it simply print the value of i or x to the HTML.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same question, now i know i have made a funny mistake. You must read this statement in a wrong way like me. This second argument need a string, so "ratingsSet("+i+","+x+");" means

> "ratingsSet("+
> i
> +","+
> x
> +"):"

so this argument will become a string. There are no +x+
:)