# C++: disable implicit conversion warnings

Tags: c++, warnings, compiler-warnings, implicit-conversion, flags

I'm using MSVC, but it would be a plus to mention the right flags for the other major compilers. I need the flags just for experimental purposes. These are some examples of the warnings I'm referring to:

`warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'T' to 'int', possible loss of data`

`warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'Uint8', possible loss of data`

`warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'U' to 'T', possible loss of data`

`warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data`

`warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'float' to 'T', possible loss of data`

`warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'float' to 'T', possible loss of data`

`warning C4838: conversion from 'float' to 'T' requires a narrowing conversion`

Comment: Do you want just some flags for some compilers?

Comment: Yes, if I didn't misunderstood ur question

Comment: You can find some info [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088460/flags-to-enable-thorough-and-verbose-g-warnings).

Comment: You should fix those problems in your code rather than silence warnings.

Comment: user7860670, I mentioned I need them for experimental purposes...
@dasfex, I need to disable just warnings about implicit conversion... I wanted someone who knows well this field to point right away what I need. I could've looked in all the possible flags if I wanted this way, but I don't understand every description

Comment: even for experimental purpose you should prefer a proper cast instead of silencing the warning.

Comment: errors, tell you that the is a syntactical problem preventing the code to compile, warnings tell about potential problems, that can make a program misbehave at runtime. You should not disable the warnings about implicit conversion, but to a valid explicitly one instead.

Comment: In this case, while suggesting better choices, can u all also mention the flags I wanted in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable warning in MSVC++2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440614/disable-warning-in-msvc2010)

Comment: [How can we disable implicit casting in MSVC C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868858), and more if your search for e.g. `MSVC disable C4244 warning`

Comment: Thx @t.niese . Is not an automatic flag which refers too all conversions (if it existed in the first place), but it does its job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to silence an error you can do that as shown in [the official documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=vs-2019). MSVC has warning levels, and each warning is assigned to a level. So you either change the level what should be reported, assign a certain warning to a different level, or silence a specific waring.

- `/wdnnnn` would silence an error `nnnn` is the warning number.
- `/wxnnnn` changes the level of a warning `x` is the new level, `nnnn` the warning number.

Or you can do that in a file basis using `#pragma`

But there is no flag for each conversion, you have to do that for each of the `Cnnnn` manually.